# How to validate/limit numeric inputs in ionic forms?

Tags: forms, typescript, validation, ionic-framework, ionic4

`<ion-input type="number" formControlName="title" max="{{max}}" (change)="changetodo($event)"></ion-input>`

here i use max field and bind it with max variable in ts file. but still i can input values above the max field. how can i fix it?

Comment: Can you tag the language you're using?  Also would be very helpful if you could post the code you're using, the errors you're getting, and the desired result, as well as any relevant inputs and things you've already tried.

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="number" pattern="[0-9]+" min="{{number.min}}" max="{{number.max}}"[(ngModel)]="number.answer">
```

But you would also need validation code in your .ts file.

Just take note I had issues myself with 0 being identified as undefined.

Solution for empty input:

```
let numAnswer = parseInt(number.answer);
if(typeof number.answer === 'undefined'){
          this.errorMessage = "Please provide an answer";
          return false;
}
```

Solution for 0:

```
 if (number.min != numAnswer && numAnswer === 0) {
          this.errorMessage = "The answer must be more than " + number.min;
          return false;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

The max and min are not working for me too. I'm using to Android App.

Workaround using your code was sample:

```
<ion-input type="number" (ionChange)="changetodo()" [(ngModel)]="inputvalue"></ion-input>
<p *ngIf="msginputvalue">Must be between {{min}} and {{max}}</p>
```

You must use (ionChange) instead of (change) and use [(ngModel)]="inputvalue" too.

in your .ts :

```
  changetodo() {
console.log(this.inputvalue);
if (this.inputvalue < this.min || this.peso > this.max)
  this.msginputvalue = true;
else
  this.msginputvalue = false;
```

}